# How to calculate p-values for each feature in R using two sample t-test

Tags: r, statistics

I have two data frames cases and controls and I performed two sample t-test as shown below.But I am doing feature extraction from the feature set of (1299 features/columns) so I want to calculate p-values for each feature. Based on the p-value generated for each feature I want to reject or accept the null hypothesis.

Can anyone explain to me how the below output is interpreted and how to calculate the p-values for each feature?

```
t.test(New_data_zero,New_data_one)
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  New_data_zero_pca and New_data_one_pca
t = -29.086, df = 182840000, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.02499162 -0.02183612
sample estimates:
 mean of x  mean of y 
0.04553462 0.06894849
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at ?t.test. x and y are supposed to be vectors not matrixes. So the function is automatically converting them to vectors. What you want to do, assuming that columns are features and the two matrixes have the same features, is:

```
pvals=vector()
for (i in seq(ncol(New_data_zero))){
 pvals[i]=t.test(New_data_zero[,i], New_data_one[,i])$p.value
}
```

Then you can look at pvals (probably in log scale) and after multiple hypothesis testing correction (see ?p.adjust).

Answer (score 0):

Let's also address the enormously bad idea of this approach to finding differences among your features. Even if all of the effects between these 1299 features are literally zero you will find *significant results in 0.05 of all possible 1299 2-way comparisons which makes this strategy effectively meaningless. I would strongly suggest taking a look at an introductory statistics text, especially the section on family-wise type I error rates before proceeding.